# How to get date from datetime format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a datetime for eg:23/9/2009 10:00:00 AM .I want to get date from datetime.Means 23/9/2009 .Can anybody help

Answer (score 10):

Just do

```
DateTime dateOnly = myDateTime.Date;
```

To display it as a date you can do

```
string dateString = dateOnly.ToShortDateString();
```

Note, that ToShortDateString will work even with a time component.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it this way:

```
DateTime.Parse("23/9/2009 10:00:00").Date.ToString()
```

Comment: There are two problems with your code; it will throw an exception if it's run in another locale than US (or one that has the same date format), and it will print the 00:00:00 for the time.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the .Date property will give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Searching the web always helps.

Google 'datetime msdn' and you'll get the best [reference material](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Another way besides the ToShortDateString Function.
Here we use a format string to get our result.

```
dim myDateFormat as String = "MM/d/yyyy"
dim myDateTime as DateTime = DateTime.Now    'Displays: 1/17/2014 2:33:23 PM
dim myDateOnly as DateTime = myDateTime.ToString(format)     'Displays: 1/17/2004
```